# Convert the Html Table data into json format data to re-bind

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

I have normal html table data with colspan th tags and multiple rows of data ,  so now i want to create json format of html table rows data of [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPzDs.png) to rebind dynamically through property.

I am attaching the Stackblitz url for ur refrence :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablecolgroup-demo-hkb9wj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I am unable to solve this .

Please help me on this issue

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please share what output json you are expecting!

Comment: I want to create a new  json format for table rows data to re bind it on ui without hardcoded data in html..for reference i added imge in question